# Slide out tab flys back too far (off the page)

Tags: jquery, tabs, slide

I have implemented a slide out div on my site that sits on the left hand side of the page. A small handle can be clicked which pulls the tab back and forth.

[Live example here](http://www.rubytuesdaycreative.co.uk/testsite/snood.html)

At present the CSS, as follows, is set to 500px width. I want 250px width instead.

```
.panel {
  width:500px;
  min-height:175px;
  padding:40px;
  position:fixed;
  left:-580px;
  top:29.5%;
  z-index:1;
  background:#4d5290;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 25px 0px;
border-radius: 0px 0px 25px 0px;
}

  .panel .trigger {
    width:36px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:-36px;
  }
```

I halved the width to width to `250px` and then assumed I could halve the `left:-580px` value to gain the result I wanted.

However the slide out tab slides outwards just fine, but when you click the handle again to hide the tab, it flys back the original 580px off the page (meaning you then can't view it or get it back.)

I've tried to get it working in a JS Fiddle but am struggling because the JS file won't behave properly in a js fiddle... working on it. In the mean time everything that is needed can be seen at:

[The page/live site](http://www.rubytuesdaycreative.co.uk/testsite/snood.html)
[The JS linked file](http://www.rubytuesdaycreative.co.uk/testsite/js/slideout.js)

Hope someone can help me work out what it's doing. Or what the formula is for the difference between the numbers?

Comment: Checkout slideout.js file, line #26 ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.panel {
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 175px;
    padding: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    left: -330px; //you have 40px of padding, we need to add that to this calculation.
    top: 29.5%;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #4D5290;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 25px;
}
```

the jQuery change...

```
$(settings.objSlidePanel).animate({
    'left' : '-330px'
});
```

[Your code live in action -- click here](http://jsfiddle.net/5jLUv/)

**Edit**

It's also quite possible you have markup issues, when I copied it over from your site, your img tag rendered like `<img src="blahblahblah.ext" <=" div=""/>`. This could be causing you issues elsewhere, probably not with this code.

Also check that you have not hardcoded `style="left:-580px"` into the `<div>` its self.

Comment: The jQuery needs to be set to `'left' : '-330px'` like your css otherwise it doesnt slide all the way back. Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/5jLUv/1/